# How come my databinding is writing out the Length property?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, datagrid

So I've setup a viewmodel to where it binds an `ObservableCollection<string>` to my DataGrid.

It prints out the value just fine but it also prints out the Length of the property? I don't recall ever setting that in any binding whatsoever. Why is it doing that?

[image: Visual representation of what it looks like]

My MainWindow.cs

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new MasterViewModel();
}
```

MasterViewModel.cs

```
class MasterViewModel
{
    public Users Users { get; } = new Users();
    public Achievements Achievements { get; } = new Achievements();
}
```

Users.cs

```
class Users : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Users()
    {
        newList.Add("Hello there");
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> newList = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public ObservableCollection<string> NewList
    {
        get { return newList; }
        set { newList = value; }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Users.NewList}" Width="400" Height="200" Margin="182,158,210,61">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataGrid has property `AutoGenerateColumns` which is set to `True` by default and makes DataGrid to create a column for each property defined in items.

DataGrid is bound to `NewList` which contains items of type `string` which has Length property. So it makes `Length` column

you can disable auto-generation by setting `<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ...`

Comment: Yeah I notticed that anhd posted an answer myself, appriciate it I'll mark yours as the right one, any ideas to why it choses the `length` property of all of them?

Comment: all of them? `string` doesn't have other  properties except `Length`

Comment: Oh.. I thought a string had way more properties.. Hm.

Comment: No seems to be length and Chars

Comment: @MarkDenom, `Chars` is a name for the [indexer](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,716) which return char symbol at a certain index. Indexer is not included in auto generation, because it requires argument

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add the property `AutoGenerateColumns="False"`.
Not sure why it was set to true by default or why it woudl choose the `length` property of all the properties but I guess I got it fixed.