# Datagrid ItemsSource won't add the List

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

Good Morning,
I'm facing a very strange problem with a DataGrid in WPF.
I'm trying to add the list of file inside a specific folder, but the grid remains blank. Could you please explain me why?
That's my code:

```
private static readonly string _sharedFolder = Settings.GetShared();
private readonly DirectoryInfo _disF = new DirectoryInfo(_sharedFolder);

private void LoadRecipe_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FileInfo[] _sFFiles = _sF.GetFiles("*.csv");
    List<string> filesList = new List<string>();
    foreach (FileInfo file in _sFFiles)
    {
        filesList.Add(file.Name);
    }

    Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(Function.SetLanguageDictionary());
    Title = Function.GetTranslatedValue("LoadRecipe", Settings.GetLang());
    DatagridRecipes.ItemsSource = filesList;
    FoundRecipesLabel.Content = Function.GetTranslatedValue("FoundRecipes", Settings.GetLang());
    ButtonLoadRecipe.Content = Function.GetTranslatedValue("Load", Settings.GetLang());
}
```

I've also tried (inside the foreach) to print out the file.Name and I've got the right output.
I don't really know why is not working.
The only thing that I get every time is the `file.Name.Length` value.

[image: LoadRecipe]

Somebody can give me an hint?

Thank you in advance

**EDIT**

Here's the XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="ButtonLoadRecipe" Content="Load" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,0,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Style="{DynamicResource SquareMetroButton}" Height="40" Click="ButtonLoadRecipe_Click"/>
    <DataGrid x:Name="DatagridRecipes" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="351" Margin="10,65,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="274" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionChanged="DatagridRecipes_SelectionChanged"/>
    <Label x:Name="FoundRecipesLabel" Content="RecipesFound" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    <Separator HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="19" Margin="10,46,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="274"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How come my databinding is writing out the Length property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50390576/how-come-my-databinding-is-writing-out-the-length-property)

Comment: As a note, avoid the loop by `var filesList = _sF.EnumerateFiles("*.csv").Select(f => f.Name).ToList();`

Comment: @ASh TY, didn't see it. Right now I get a blank value instead of the actual file.Name

Comment: Can you show us the XAML where you want t display the file names?

Comment: @bit here you go....

Comment: @andrepogg, since you have a list of `string`, it is probably simpler to just use ListBox instead of DataGrid. DataGrid is supposed to be editable. And it stays blank because there is no columns. When autogenerate is disabled, you need to declare `<DataGrid.Columns>`

Comment: @ASh I'll try right now

Comment: @ASh If you want to add an answer I'll mark this thread as answered ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in [How come my databinding is writing out the Length property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50390576/how-come-my-databinding-is-writing-out-the-length-property) I answered where `Length` column comes from: it is auto-generated by DataGrid because columns auto-generation for properties is enabled by default and string has only property `Length`.

to get rid of "Length" column, set `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` and define `<DataGrid.Columns>` like in the linked question.

Binding string collection to DataGrid is a known "gotcha": [WPF: Bind DataGrid to List<String>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872916/wpf-bind-datagrid-to-liststring). DataGrid is supposed to be editable, but editing won't work with string items.

---

For your situation - display a list of string with possibility to select them - it is simpler to use `ListBox` instead of `DataGrid`